How to change data in child view when inheriting?
Good afternoon everyone. Guys, tell me how it is possible to configure parent controllers during inheritance?
I have this diagram:
MenuViewController --|> CollectionViewController
--|> FilterCollectionViewController --|> MapsViewController
In the MapsViewController I want to configure the FilterCollectionViewController and CollectionViewController.

I can’t understand why I can’t subscribe to delegate IHandlerFilterCollectionDelegate and ISettingFilterCollectionDelegate?
import UIKit

protocol IMapsViewLogic: AnyObject {
    func renderFilter(filter: [String])
    func renderMaps(maps: [MapModel])
}

final class MapsViewController: CollectionViewController {

    // MARK: - Dependencies
    var iterator: IMainIterator?

    // MARK: - Public properties

    // MARK: - Private properties
    private var modelDisplay: [MapModel] = []

    // MARK: - Initializator
    init(menuDelegate: IMenuDelegate, itemMenu: MenuItem) {
        super.init()
        headerMenu = HeaderMenuViewController(menuItem: itemMenu, delegate: menuDelegate)
        handlerCellDelegate = self
        delegateSettingCell = self

        handlerFilterCellDelegate = self
        delegateSettingFilterCell = self
        print("Maps view controller \(itemMenu)")
    }

    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    // MARK: - Public methods
}

extension MapsViewController: IHandlerCollectionDelegate {
    func getCount() -> Int {
        modelDisplay.count
    }
    
    func itemSelect(index: Int) {
        print("Collection View Map \(index)")
    }
    
    func addToFavourite(index: Int) {
        print("Add favourite \(index)")
    }
}

extension MapsViewController: ISettingCollectionDelegate {
    func createCell(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let item = modelDisplay[indexPath.row]

        if let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(
            withReuseIdentifier: MapCell().reuseIdentifier,
            for: indexPath
        ) as? MapCell {
            cell.reloadData(modelCell: item)
            return cell
        }
        return UICollectionViewCell()
    }

    func registerCell(collectionView: UICollectionView) {
        collectionView.register(MapCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: MapCell().reuseIdentifier)
    }
    
    func calculateCellSize(screenWidth: CGFloat) -> CGSize {
        let sizeCollectionView = (view.bounds.width - GlobalSizes.Padding.paddingScreen) / 2
        let sizeCellWidth = (sizeCollectionView - 16)
        let sizeCellHeight = sizeCellWidth * 1.05
        return CGSize(width: sizeCellWidth, height: sizeCellHeight)
    }
}

extension MapsViewController: IHandlerFilterCollectionDelegate {
// Here I want to reconfigure the collectionFilterView?
}

extension MapsViewController: ISettingFilterCollectionDelegate {
// Here I want to reconfigure the collectionFilterView?

}

// MARK: - Render logic.
extension MapsViewController: IMapsViewLogic {
    func renderFilter(filter: [String]) {

    }

    func renderMaps(maps: [MapModel]) {
        self.modelDisplay = maps
        reloadCollectionView()
    }
}

import UIKit

// Обработка ячейки коллекции.
protocol IHandlerCollectionDelegate: AnyObject {
    func itemSelect(index: Int)
    func addToFavourite(index: Int)
    func getCount() -> Int
}

// Настройка ячейки коллекции.
protocol ISettingCollectionDelegate: AnyObject {
    func createCell(collectionView:  UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell
    func registerCell(collectionView:  UICollectionView)
    func calculateCellSize(screenWidth: CGFloat) -> CGSize
}

class CollectionViewController: FilterCollectionViewController {

    // MARK: - Dependencies
    var handlerCellDelegate: IHandlerCollectionDelegate!
    var delegateSettingCell: ISettingCollectionDelegate!

    // MARK: - Public properties
    lazy var collectionView = createCollectionView()

    // MARK: - Private properties

    // MARK: - Initializator
    override init() {
        super.init()
    }

    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    // MARK: - Public methods
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        setupConfiguration()
        addUIView()
    }

    override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
        setupLayout()
    }

    func reloadCollectionView() {
        collectionView.reloadData()
    }
}

// MARK: - Add UIView.
private extension CollectionViewController {
    /// Добавление элементов UIView в Controller.
    func addUIView() {
        view.addSubview(collectionView)
    }
}

// MARK: - UI configuration.
private extension CollectionViewController {
    /// Настройка UI элементов
    func setupConfiguration() {
        collectionView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear

        delegateSettingCell.registerCell(collectionView: collectionView)
        collectionView.delegate = self
        collectionView.dataSource = self
        collectionView.layer.cornerRadius = GlobalSizes.Radius.cellMap
        collectionView.clipsToBounds = true
        collectionView.layer.borderWidth = 1
    }
}

// MARK: - Add constraint.
private extension CollectionViewController {
    func setupLayout() {
        let topPadding = GlobalSizes.Padding.paddingScreen
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            collectionView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: collectionFilterView.bottomAnchor, constant: topPadding),
            collectionView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leftAnchor, constant: topPadding),
            collectionView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.rightAnchor, constant: -topPadding),
            collectionView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor)
        ])
    }
}

// MARK: - CollectionView Flow Layout.
extension CollectionViewController {
    /// Настройка размеров ячейки.
    override func collectionView(
        _ collectionView: UICollectionView,
        layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout,
        sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath
    ) -> CGSize {
        delegateSettingCell.calculateCellSize(screenWidth: view.bounds.width)
    }
}

// MARK: - CollectionView Source and Delegate.
extension CollectionViewController {
    // Действие на ячейку.
    override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        handlerCellDelegate.itemSelect(index: indexPath.row)
    }

    // Количество ячеек в секции.
    override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        handlerCellDelegate.getCount()
    }

    // Регистрация ячейки и заполнение данными.
    override func collectionView(
        _ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath
    ) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        delegateSettingCell.createCell(collectionView: collectionView, cellForItemAt: indexPath)
    }
}

// MARK: - UI Fabric.
private extension CollectionViewController {
    func createCollectionView() -> UICollectionView {
        let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
        layout.minimumInteritemSpacing = 16
        layout.minimumLineSpacing = 16
        layout.scrollDirection = .vertical
        let collectionView = UICollectionView(frame: .zero, collectionViewLayout: layout)
        collectionView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = false
        collectionView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        return collectionView
    }
}


import UIKit

protocol IFilterCollectionModel {
    var title: String { get }
}

struct MockModel: IFilterCollectionModel {
    var title: String
}

// Обработка ячейки коллекции фильтра.
protocol IHandlerFilterCollectionDelegate: AnyObject {
    func itemSelect(index: Int)

}

// Настройка ячейки коллекции фильтра.
protocol ISettingFilterCollectionDelegate: AnyObject {
    func createCell(collectionView:  UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell
    func registerCell(collectionView:  UICollectionView)
    func calculateCellSize(screenWidth: CGFloat) -> CGSize
}

class FilterCollectionViewController: MenuViewController {

    // MARK: - Dependencies
    var handlerFilterCellDelegate: IHandlerFilterCollectionDelegate!
    var delegateSettingFilterCell: ISettingFilterCollectionDelegate!

    // MARK: - Public properties
    lazy var collectionFilterView = createCollectionView()

    // MARK: - Private properties
    var modelFilterForDisplay: [IFilterCollectionModel] = []

    // MARK: - Initializator
    override init() {
        super.init()
    }

    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    // MARK: - Public methods
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        setupConfiguration()
        addUIView()
    }

    override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
        setupLayout()
    }
}

// MARK: - Add UIView.
private extension FilterCollectionViewController {
    /// Добавление элементов UIView в Controller.
    func addUIView() {
        view.addSubview(collectionFilterView)
    }
}

// MARK: - UI configuration.
private extension FilterCollectionViewController {
    /// Настройка UI элементов
    func setupConfiguration() {
        collectionFilterView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear

        delegateSettingFilterCell?.registerCell(collectionView: collectionFilterView)
        collectionFilterView.delegate = self
        collectionFilterView.dataSource = self
        collectionFilterView.layer.borderWidth = 1
        collectionFilterView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.blue.cgColor
    }
}

// MARK: - Add constraint.
private extension FilterCollectionViewController {
    func setupLayout() {
        let topPadding = GlobalSizes.Padding.paddingScreen
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            collectionFilterView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: headerMenu.bottomAnchor, constant: topPadding),
            collectionFilterView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leftAnchor, constant: topPadding),
            collectionFilterView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.rightAnchor),
            collectionFilterView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: GlobalSizes.Size.littleButtonMenu.height)
        ])
    }
}

// MARK: - CollectionView Flow Layout.
extension FilterCollectionViewController: UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {
    /// Настройка размеров ячейки.
    func collectionView(
        _ collectionView: UICollectionView,
        layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout,
        sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath
    ) -> CGSize {
        delegateSettingFilterCell.calculateCellSize(screenWidth: view.bounds.width)
    }
}

// MARK: - CollectionView Source and Delegate.
extension FilterCollectionViewController: UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate  {
    // Действие на ячейку.
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        delegateSettingFilterCell.registerCell(collectionView: collectionView)
    }

    // Количество ячеек в секции.
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        modelFilterForDisplay.count
    }

    // Регистрация ячейки и заполнение данными.
    func collectionView(
        _ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath
    ) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        delegateSettingFilterCell.createCell(collectionView: collectionView, cellForItemAt: indexPath)
    }
}

// MARK: - UI Fabric.
private extension FilterCollectionViewController {
    func createCollectionView() -> UICollectionView {
        let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
        layout.minimumInteritemSpacing = 12
        layout.minimumLineSpacing = 12
        layout.scrollDirection = .horizontal
        let collectionView = UICollectionView(frame: .zero, collectionViewLayout: layout)
        collectionView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = false
        collectionView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        return collectionView
    }
}

import UIKit

class MenuViewController: UIViewController {

    // MARK: - Public properties
    var headerMenu: UIView!

    // MARK: - Private properties
    private lazy var imageBackground = createImage()

    // MARK: - Initializator
    init() {
        super.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
    }

    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    // MARK: - Public methods
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        setupConfiguration()
        addUIView()
    }

    override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
        setupLayout()
    }

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(true, animated: false)
    }


}

// MARK: - Add UIView.
private extension MenuViewController {
    func addUIView() {
        let views: [UIView] = [imageBackground, headerMenu]
        views.forEach(view.addSubview)
    }
}

// MARK: - UI configuration.
private extension MenuViewController {
    /// Настройка UI элементов
    func setupConfiguration() {
        view.backgroundColor = FlatColor.Green.darkGreen
        headerMenu.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    }
}

// MARK: - Add constraint.
private extension MenuViewController {
    func setupLayout() {
        let saveAreaTop = view.safeAreaInsets.top
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            imageBackground.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor),
            imageBackground.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor),
            imageBackground.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leftAnchor),
            imageBackground.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.rightAnchor),

            headerMenu.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor, constant: saveAreaTop),
            headerMenu.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leftAnchor, constant: GlobalSizes.Padding.paddingScreen),
            headerMenu.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.rightAnchor, constant: -GlobalSizes.Padding.paddingScreen),
            headerMenu.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: GlobalSizes.Height.heightHeaderMenu),
        ])
    }
}

// MARK: - UI Fabric.
private extension MenuViewController {
    func createImage() -> UIImageView {
        let image = UIImage(named: "Images/Backgrounds/backgroundMask")
        let imageView = UIImageView(image: image)
        imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
        imageView.alpha = 0.5
        imageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        return imageView
    }
}


If I add protocol methods myself, it writes an error. -
Type 'MapsViewController' does not conform to protocol 'IHandlerCollectionDelegate'

Your inheritance chain doesn't make a lot of sense. These seem to be unrelated view controllers in some cases. Regardless, you need to provide more clarity around your question. What errors are you seeing? What lines?  You seem to have even more inheritance than you have shown.

This issue has been resolved. Renamed IHandlerFilterCollectionDelegate and ISettingFilterCollectionDelegate protocol methods.
